# Get server name in javascript

Tags: javascript, url

I have a problem to call my URI with HTTP request in javascript.

When I use my dev server the domain name is like this :
devdomainname.com

In this case no problem.

But my test server name is like this :
testdomainname.com/test

And when I call a HTTP request like this $http.get("uri") the result is :
testdomainname.com/uri

But I want this :
testdomainname.com/test/uri

Do you have any solutions ?

Thank you very much

Comment: I do not understand. Can you clarify what the problem is? Can you show some code?

Comment: i dont really understand your question but how about $http.get("test/uri")

Comment: what server-side technology are you using ? nodejs ?

Answer (score 0):

It's `$http.get("/test/uri")` because it's in the /test folder i guess..

Answer (score 0):

No "test" is not a folder, it's a part of my server name.

In the case where my server name is classic (without subdomain), I have no problem. But when my server name contain subdomains, he cuts the subdomains and he keeps only the domain first part when I call a URI with a HTTP request.

I use angularJS in front-end and Spring MVC in back-end.

AngularJS :

```
$scope.submitLogin = function (credentials) {
    return $http.post('/login', credentials);
};
```

Java :

```
@RequestMapping(value="/login", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public Map<String,Object> login(HttpServletRequest request, @RequestBody User user) {
    ...........
}
```

If the server name is devserver.com/ ==> no problem.

If the server name is testserver.com/test ==> problem : the request call testserver.com/login but I want testserver.com/test/login